# PHP AJAX Drop Down using JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to get link two drop down using ajax with data in json format. I tried the following code, but it only shows blank drop down for departments as well as projects. I am not sure where my code is wrong.

Code of the main page index.php is given below:

```
<?php
include_once("includes/connection.php");?>
<html><head> <script type="text/Javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/Javascript">
    function showdept(){
        $('#deptdropdown').empty();
        $('#deptdropdown').append("<option> Loading...</option>");
        $('#projectdropdown').append("<option value='0'> All Projects </option>");

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"departmentdropdown.php",
            contentType:"application/json; charset:utf-8",
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data){
                $('#deptdropdown').empty();
                $('#deptdropdown').append("<option value='0'> All Departments </option>");
                $.each(data,function(i,item){
                    $('#deptdropdown').append('<option value="'+ data[i].deptID +'">'+ data[i].deptname +'</option>');
                });
            },
            complete: function(){
            }
        });
    }

     function showproject(departmentID){        
        $('#projectdropdown').empty();
        $('#projectdropdown').append("<option> Loading...</option>");
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"projectdropdown.php",
            contentType:"application/json; charset:utf-8",
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data){
                $('#projectdropdown').empty();
                $('#projectdropdown').append("<option value='0'> All Projects </option>");
                $.each(data,function(i,item){
                    $('#projectdropdown').append('<option value="'+ data[i].projectID +'">'+ data[i].projectname+'</option>');
                });
            },
            complete: function(){
            }
        });
    } 

    $(document).ready(function(){
        showdept();
         $("#deptdropdown").change(function(){
            var deptid= $("#deptdropdown").val();
            showproject(deptid);
        }); 
    }); 
</script></head><body>  <span>Departments</span><br />
<select id="deptdropdown"></select>
<br /><br />
<span>Projects</span><br />
<select id="projectdropdown"></select>  </body></html>
```

The code for the departmentdropdown.php file is as below:

```
<?php
include_once("includes/connection.php");
$query=" SELECT deptID, deptname FROM departmentdetails WHERE active_status=1 ORDER BY deptname";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $data=array();
    while($array=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $data[] = array('deptID' => $array['deptID'], 'deptname' => $array['deptname']);
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);?>
```

The code for the projectdropdown.php file is as below:

```
<?php
include_once("includes/connection.php");

$query="SELECT projectID, deptID projectname FROM projectdetails WHERE active_status=1 AND deptID='".$_GET['departmentID']."' ORDER BY projectname";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $data=array();
    while($array=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $data[] = array('proID' => $array['projectID'], 'depID' => $array['deptID'], 'projectname' => $array['projectname']);
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missing  `+` after `data[i].deptID` and `data[i].projectID`.Change the following

`showdept()`

```
$('#deptdropdown').append('<option value="'+ data[i].deptID '">'+ data[i].deptname +'</option>');
```

`showproject(departmentID)`

```
$('#projectdropdown').append('<option value="'+ data[i].projectID'">'+ data[i].projectname+'</option>');
```

to

`showdept()`

```
 $('#deptdropdown').append('<option value="'+ data[i].deptID +'">'+ data[i].deptname +'</option>');
```

`showproject(departmentID)`

```
$('#projectdropdown').append('<option value="'+ data[i].projectID +'">'+ data[i].projectname+'</option>');
```

Comment: Did the changes you suggested, now the department shows 'Loading..' while the project shows 'All Projects'

Comment: you are appending that 'Loading..' as an option, does the department dropdown has any other value in it?

Comment: Yes, it should be pulling department values from the database.

Comment: Are you getting any error on console?check whether the ajax call returns the department results or not

Comment: seems like I missed out on basic array bracket syntax. I had used curly brackets instead of round. It is working fine now. Thanks. Could not vote ur answer up due to lack of reputation though.